# difference between code polymorphism examples

Tags: java, polymorphism, abstract-class, abstract, abstraction

```
package practice;

public abstract class OutterClass {

    public int getMaxRows() {
    }

    public abstract boolean gameOver();
}

public class InnerClass extends OutterClass{

    @Override
    public boolean gameOver() {

        //int lastRow = getMaxRows() - 1;
        //int lastRow = this.getMaxRows() - 1;
        //int lastRow = ((OutterClass)this).getMaxRows() - 1;
        //int lastRow = ((InnerClass)this).getMaxRows() - 1;
        //int lastRow = InnerClass.this.getMaxRows() - 1;

    }
```

What is the difference between all of the commented out code in the sublass (InnerClass)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// int lastRow = getMaxRows() - 1;
// int lastRow = this.getMaxRows() - 1;
// int lastRow = ((OutterClass)this).getMaxRows() - 1;
// int lastRow = ((InnerClass)this).getMaxRows() - 1;
```

These are all identical in effect. The last is especially pointless.

```
// int lastRow = InnerClass.this.getMaxRows() - 1;
```

This won't compile.

NB Contrary to your nomenclature, there are no inner classes here.